# If the numbers in one set are all larger than those in another set, are there numbers in between?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, order-theory

Let $S, R \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be sets of real numbers such that for every $s \in S$ and $r \in R$, $s<r$. How can one prove that there exists some real number $t$ satisfying $s <t <r$ for all $s\in S$ and $r \in R$?

Comment: This isn't true without some additional assumption. E.g., $S = (-\infty, 0)$ and $R = [0, \infty)$ satisfy the assumption stated but no such $t$ exists for this choice of $S$ and $R$. It is true if the sets are both open or if they are both closed.